# play framework unable to run an existing project

Tags: java, playframework

I'm a rookie developer trying to run an application using play framework. I've followed the tutorial and can successfully create a new project.

However when I go to the directory that has the project I'm supposed to work on and enter the play command I get the following error:

```
[error] Not a valid command: play (similar: last, alias, loadp)
[error] Not a valid project ID: play
[error] Not a valid configuration: play
[error] Not a valid key: play (similar: clean)
[error] play
```

I have very little knowledge regarding the framework and don't know where to start correcting my mistake. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you running Play Framework version 2.0 or an 1.2.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the version difference of play. The project I was suppose to work on was developed in play 1.2 where as I installed the version 2.0 .

By the way, working with 2.0 on a project developed by version 1.2 is possible, but I strongly recommend not to do it that way as there are problems on the later stages as well.

Answer (score 3):

You have to run the play command this way:

```
./play cmd [app_path] [--options]
```

where in case of running a project, it is

```
./play run /path/to/projectname
```

Comment: This helped for me. Not sure why it does not work the way the tutorial specifies though http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/NewApplication

Answer (score 2):

I am facing this problem in the context of sub projects.

This is what worked for me.

---

**Code:**

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val helloWorldProj = Project(id = "HelloWorld", base = file("helloworld"))    

  val appName = "WebApp"
  val appVersion = "1.0"
  val appDependencies = Seq()

  val webAppProj = PlayProject( appName, appVersion, appDependencies, path = file("webapp"), mainLang = PlayProject.SCALA)
    .dependsOn(helloWorldProj)
    .aggregate(helloWorldProj)

}
```

On running the `play` command, I get the following error:

**Error:**

```
[info] Set current project to HelloWorld (in build file:/D:/EclipseProjects/HelloWorldPlayMultiProject/)
[error] Not a valid command: play (similar: last, alias, loadp)
[error] Not a valid project ID: play
[error] Not a valid configuration: play
[error] Not a valid key: play (similar: play-hash, play-dist, play-conf)
[error] play
[error]     ^
```

**Solution:**

Now, if I rename `helloWorldProj` as `zhelloWorldProj`, it works!
In this case, `play` sets the active project to `WebApp`.(Since `webAppProj` variable name alphabetically comes before `zhelloWorldProj`)

I can then change the active project to `HelloWorld` by giving the command `project HelloWorld`.

I think this has something to do with how `sbt` finds the Project objects using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Need to have more detail about your environment (OS, Play version etc) but if you are getting errors that play is not a valid command, my first course of action would be to check that the path to play.sh (I assume you are using non-windows) is included in your system path?

Answer (score 1):

I delete all directories in the project folder and it works. Do not delete files (build.properties, Build.scala and plugins.sbt)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language you're using, make sure one of the following is in your build.sbt file: 
    play.Project.playJavaSettings 
    play.Project.playScalaSettings

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem! What happened was in my /user/xxx/project folder there were old projects from 1.x version. Deleting that folder worked for me!